# How to make separate button functions in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, button, menu

I have a class called Menu and inside that class I want to place a menu of buttons such as buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, and so on. However when I run the app on my phone I cant tap buttonB before I tap buttonA. If I tap buttonA first, I can choose buttonA or buttonB all I want. The question is how do you separate the buttons in the Menu class to be able to tap any button at any time?

```
package com.emods.app1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONA"));

    Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONB"));
        }
        });
        }

    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take your btnB and place it outside your onClick event for btnA. Currently you have your declaration for btnB inside your onClick event for btnA.

```
Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {             
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONA"));      
    }         
});   
Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);     
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View v) {             
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONB"));         
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONA"));
    }
});

Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONB"));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the listener for the second button inside the listener for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting issue.

Change:

```
Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONA"));

Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONB"));
    }
    });
    }

});
```

to:

```
Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONA"));
    }
});

Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONB"));
    }
```

});

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Only the brackets are wrong:

```
package com.emods.app1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONA"));
        }
    });

    Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent ("com.emods.app1.BUTTONB"));

        }
    });
}

}
```

You should activate the automatic formatting in your IDE.